# Is there a way to dynamically turn a sentence into a tree with NLTK?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, nltk, grammar, context-free-grammar

I'm trying to make a non-string-similarity powered A.I. in **python 3.8.9** that can understand natural language structure including the subject, verb and object in a sentence to then process it and give back feedback but also learn in the process.
I'm using [**NLTK**](https://www.nltk.org/index.html) and so far I've been able to *word tokenize* sentences and *tag* the thrown words.
I'm trying to get the script to dynamically turn a given sentence into a tree but with *RegexParser* I have to feed it my own specific grammar which can only be applied to some sentences. I found this example on the web:

```
import nltk
from nltk import RegexpParser
from nltk.tree import *
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')

#STRING
sentence = input()
#TOKENIZE
words = nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence))

RegexpParser("""
                    NP: {<DT>?<JJ>?<NN>} #To extract Noun Phrases
                    P: {<IN>}            #To extract Prepositions
                    V: {<V.*>}           #To extract Verbs
                    PP: {<p> <NP>}       #To extract Prepositional Phrases
                    VP: {<V> <NP|PP>*}   #To extract Verb Phrases
                    """).parse(words).pretty_print()
```

Which gave me back:

```
                         S                                   
          _______________|________________________            
         |               VP        |              |          
         |               |         |              |           
         NP              V         P              NP         
   ______|______         |         |       _______|______     
The/DT red/JJ fox/NN jumped/VBD over/IN the/DT lazy/JJ dog/NN
```

Though it's not too bad, I was hoping for something like this:

```
                         S                                   
          _______________|
         |               VP
         |               |------------------------
         |               |         |              |
         NP              V         P              NP         
   ______|______         |         |       _______|______     
The/DT red/JJ fox/NN jumped/VBD over/IN the/DT lazy/JJ dog/NN
```

in order to obtain the subject of the sentence by splitting as `[NP, VP]`
Is there any way for **NLTK** to dynamically determine what grammar to use in *RegexpParser* in a case-by-case basis? Or is there an universal rule that can applied to all sentences (simple, complex, declarative and interrogative)?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen chapter 8 of the NLTK book?  Good starting point both on the nature of the problem, and the tools available in NLTK https://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html

Comment: I'm not sure if [RegexpParser](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.chunk.regexp.html?highlight=regexpparser#nltk.chunk.regexp.RegexpParser) is exactly what you want. It could be helpful to look for other parsers and/or other grammars as well. Above comment is absolutely right. If you're looking for a simple solution to your problem, you may get disappointed very soon. There is a whole branch of research calling Computational Linguistics or Natural Language Processing for these kind of problems.